# Let $f$ be entire so that $|f(z)| \leq M(5+|z|)^q$, for $q \in \mathbb N$ and $0<M \in \mathbb R$. Find $f's$ maximal degree.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be entire so that $|f(z)| \leq M(5+|z|)^q$, for $q \in \mathbb N$ and $0<M \in \mathbb R$. Show that $f$ is a polynimoal and find its maximal degree.

So since $f$ is entire, it seems pretty obvious to me that it must be a polynomial.

Next I tried using Cauchy's Integral Formula for the q'th derivate, but I got stuck there. I think proving $f^{(q)}(z)=0$ will suffice.

Any assistance will be great!

Comment: Why do you consider it pretty obvious that $f$ must be a polynomial?

Comment: Maybe I got it mixed up, but if $f$ is entire then can't we write it as a power series around $z_0=0$ - $f(z)=\Sigma _{n=o}^\infty a_nz^n$?

Comment: Yes, we can, but the growth behaviour of power series is not quite obvious. Of course it is true that a bound on the growth as the given one implies that $f$ is a polynomial, but it's not immediate from the fact that we can write it as a power series. The Cauchy estimates give you the conclusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f$ is entire, then for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$ we have 
$$
f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}z^n
$$
Thus, to prove that $f$ is a polynomial of degree at most $q$, it suffices to show that $f^{(n)}(0)=0$ for all $n>q$. Take any $R>0$ and $n>q$, then
$$
|f^{(n)}(0)|=\left| \frac{n!}{2\pi i} \int_{|z|=R} \frac{f(z)}{z^{n+1}}dz\right|\leq \frac{n!}{2\pi}\frac{M(5+R)^q}{R^{n+1}}2\pi R=n!\frac{M(5+R)^q}{R^{n}}
$$
However, since $(5+R)^q$ is a polynomial on $R$ with degree $q$ and $R^n$ is a polynomial on $R$ with degree $n>q$, then
$$
\lim_{R \to \infty}n!\frac{M(5+R)^q}{R^{n}} = 0
$$
Hence $|f^{(n)}(0)|=0$ for all $n>q$ which implies $f^{(n)}(0)=0$ for all $n>q$, as wanted.